# Tailwind css file very big 2.42 mib how can i reduce size this file am using laravel?

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css

[image]
Tailwind css file very big 2.42 mib how can i reduce size this file am using laravel ?

Comment: Did you try to use PurgeCSS? But first, you need to install Tailwind in your project. https://medium.com/@wearethreebears/using-purgecss-to-remove-unused-tailwind-classes-with-laravel-mix-92dffba21ed7

Answer (score 2):

The best strategy is to use generate a specific CSS specific to your need and deploy it on your own CDN

Below an example that explains how to configure TailwindCSS for a simple Html Project

1. First Step: create a package.json file

```sh
yarn init
```

2. Add tailwindcss postcss-cli and autoprefixer

```sh
yarn add tailwindcss postcss-cli autoprefixer -D
```

> yarn add tailwindcss postcss-cli autoprefixer -D

3. Create a default configuration file for TailwindCSS

```sh
npx tailwind init tailwind.js -full
```

4. Create a postcss.config.js file

```sh
touch postcss.config.js
```

5. Edit the postcss.config.js

```js
const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        tailwindcss('./tailwind.js'),
        require('autoprefixer')
    ],
 purge: [
    './src/**/*.html',
  ],
};
```

6. Create a tailwind.css as follow

```css
@import "tailwindcss/base";

@import "tailwindcss/components";

@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

7. Use postcss to generate the stylesheet style.css

```sh
npx postcss tailwind.css -o style.css
```

8. Use the stylesheet in your project

```html
<html>
 <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    </head>
 <body>
     <h1>Hello world</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

9. Deploy the style.css on a CDN

(Possible CDN : CloudFront / Netlify)

Comment: PurgeCSS reduce the size the file final css file by purging unused styles https://tailwindcss.com/docs/controlling-file-size

Answer (score 2):

Edit your tailwind.config.js and set purge.enabled = true:

```
const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');
module.exports = {
 purge: {
    enabled: true,
    content: ['./src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}']
  },
 ...
};
```

[Tailwind CSS - Optimizing for Production](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production)